# Accessing a string gives empty value even though it is assigned

Tags: c++, string, pointers, std

For a project I am making a simple text based combat game in C++, which I am not really familiar with.

I am having a problem returning a player's name into a game controller.
Using the watch feature of visual studio I can see that the name is being set when constructed, but when I try to access it in the 'getName' call, it is empty. This probably has something to do with pointers however I am unsure.

Code and pictures below.

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game() 
{
    Player user = Player("Foo");
    gameLoop();
}

void Game::gameLoop() 
{
    std::string name = user.getName();
    printf("name: %s", name.c_str());
}
```

**Game.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Player.h"


class Game
{
public:
    Game();
private:
    Player user;

    void gameLoop();
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(std::string name)
{
    playerName = name;

}

std::string Player::getName() {
    std::string nameWatch = playerName;
    return playerName;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

class Player
{
public:
    Player(std::string name);
    Player() {}

    std::string getName();

private:
    std::string playerName;
};
```

[[image: Name is set to playerName][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR4Oc.png)

[[image: Player name is now empty?][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAMuT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
Game::Game() 
{
    Player user = Player("Foo");
    gameLoop();
}
```

You create an local variable `user` which hides `this->user`.

To initialize your member variable, you may do

```
Game::Game() : user("Foo")
{
    gameLoop();
}
```

And if you have several members to initialize:

```
Game::Game() : user("Foo"), comp("Monster")
{
    gameLoop();
}
```

Doing

```
Game::Game()
{
    user = Player("Foo");
    comp = Player("Monster");
    gameLoop();
}
```

creates a default `user`/`comp` and assign after a value to them, so it requires that `Player` is default constructible

Comment: Hi, thank you for  answering so quickly - I now see what I have done wrong. I now understand that I was overwriting the header file Player constructor. However your solution seemed a bit hard to do if I had multiple players. 

I am now using this and it seems to be fine.

 
`code`
user = Player("Player");
comp = Player("Monster");
`code`

Comment: @user1972995: Surround code by back quote to highlight them on SO. Edited to handle several members.

Answer (score 1):

```
Game::Game()
{
    Player user = Player("Foo"); 
    // you create local object with name user that override class-member object 
    // with same name. At least, you have user object like class member is empty cause
    // constr initialization-list is empty, and compiler call default const for std::string class that
    // exactly empty string, and local Player object with name user that die on close brace end.

    // First of all, use "Hungarian notation" style to detect class-member variables, for example:
    // 
    // class Hello
    // {
    //  private:
    //    int m_user;
    // }


    // At second, if one of your class-members haven't default constr and you should explicit call correct 
    // constructor use "Constructor initialization-list, like
    //
    // Game::Game() :
    //  m_user("Mike")
    // {
    //
    // }

    gameLoop();
}
```